# Join 2 tables with different name using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 table first is

**Before**

```
lotname     
--------    
R16A        
R17A        
R17B        
R18A        
R18B
```

2nd is

**After**

```
lotname     
--------        
R16AA       
R17A        
R17B        
R18AAA      
R18B
```

I want to join both the table so that everything match like `R16A` should match with `R16AA`

if i write this code

```
select * from before
join after
    on before.lotname = after.lotname
```

**O/P**

```
lotname     lotname     
R17A        R17A        
R17B        R17B        
R18B        R18B
```

I want o/p like

```
Lotname     Lotname     
----------------------------                
R16A        R16AA       
R17A        R17A        
R17B        R17B        
R18A        R18AAA      
R18B        R18B
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM before
INNER JOIN after
    ON after.lotname LIKE before.lotname + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM before JOIN after ON before.Lotname = LEFT(after.Lotname,4)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM before
INNER JOIN after
ON after.lotname LIKE CONCAT(before.lotname,'%')
```